# Searching a text file and printing line numbers

Tags: python, file

How do you get your function to find the lines in the text file where the word occurs and print the corresponding line numbers?

I had to open a text file with the paragraph and then am supposed to search the paragraph for certain words and then print the specific line numbers for the words.

Here is what I have so far.

```
words = [network, devices, computer, fire, local, area, room, single]
    def index(string):
       lines = open('Network.txt', 'r')
       string = str(lines.read())
       lines.close()
       return string
```

Comment: None of that code searches the file.

Comment: I know it opens the file.  That's why I am asking!

Comment: Split the `lines` by new line using `lines = lines.split('\n')`. That returns a list with each line as an element. Then it's easy to find out which line has the words your looking for.

Comment: @Ryan its better to iterate through the file using `for line in file`, treating a file as an iterable will split on newlines (of any type) automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have opened your file correctly, this is actually quite easy. Using file.read() pulls the entire file in, which you don't want. [If you are doing line-based processing, iterate through the file using `with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) as it make opening, closing and error handling of files much easier:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        #do something
```

The core piece with your logic is [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), which takes an iterable and returns a count along with each iterated item.

```
words = ["word","another"]
for line_num,line in enumerate(file):
    if any([word in line for word in words]):
        print line_num, line
```

The other factor is the list comprehension which checks if the any word is on a line. The [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function "returns True if any element of the iterable is true". And the following list comprehension:

```
[word in line for word in words]
```

can be read as:

> `[`<sup>tell me if</sup> `word` <sup>is</sup> `in` <sup>the</sup> `line for` <sup>each</sup> `word in` <sup>all of the</sup> `words]`.

If `any` word is in that array, i.e. at least one of your words is the line, its true, and thus will be printed.

Comment: maybe 1) `any(word in line for word in words)` and `words = {"word","another"}`  (i.e., use a generator vs a list comprehension in the `any` and use a set instead of a list as the target to test for words.

Comment: I was using the data structure the OP gave for `words`, and given how short that was I just went with a plain list comprehension, as using a function with what looks like instructions in might have been confusing. `any(stuff ...)` vs `any([stuff ...])`

Answer (score 2):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a [set union](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) of the line in question if you just want to test for presence of individual words:

```
words={'some', 'target', 'words', 'in', 'a', 'set'}

with open(f_name) as fin:
    for line_num, line in enuemrate(fin):
        if set(line.split()) & words:
            print(line_num, line)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
words = []
lines = {}
for i in words:
    lines[i] = []

with open("file", "r") as fin:
    curLine = 0
    for i in fin.readLines():
        for j in words:
            if j in i:
                lines[j].append(curLine)
        curLine += 1

for i in words:
    print lines[j]
```